# Illegal reference to non static member in a struct

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When compiling with Visual Studio 2013 I get the error

```
illegal reference to non-static member 'Ice::Constants::Tau
```

And this is all of the relevant code

Maths.hpp

```
#ifndef ICE_MATHS_DEFINES_H
#define ICE_MATHS_DEFINES_H

#include "Vec2.hpp"
#include "Vec3.hpp"
#include "Vec4.hpp"
#include "Mat4.hpp"
#include "Quaternion.hpp"

namespace Ice
{
  struct Constants
  {
    static constexpr f32 Pi  = 3.14159265359;
    static constexpr f32 Tau = 6.28318530718;
  };
}

#endif
```

Offending line of code in engine.cpp

```
_context_scene.projection = perspective( Constants::Tau, aspect_ratio, 0.1f, 100.0f );
```

Perspective function

```
  Mat4 perspective( f32 fov, f32 aspect, f32 near, f32 far );
```

Comment: Show the definition of `perspective`. If it is taking the value by reference for example, that would be important to know.

Comment: i wouldnt use names starting with an underscore (they are not allowed in global namespace)

Comment: Is `perspective` a function or a member of a class?

Comment: @tobi303 That was intentional, as It only needs to be used localy.

Comment: Also wondering what version of C++ you are compiling with as C++14 may be required to do the assignment in the struct.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yes, it is.

Comment: Yes it is a function or yes it is a member?  lol

Comment: As an aside, putting constants into a struct like this is silly, in my opinion. Why not use `namespace Constants`, then you can drop the `static`.

Comment: Try it with Visual C++ 2015. Lots of updates in that one.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error on GCC 6. If I make `perspective` take a `const &` for the Tau argument, then I can get this error:

```
constexpr-test.cpp:(.text+0x1b): undefined reference to `Constants::Tau'
```

Otherwise it works fine, for me.

My only other guess is that you have unsaved changes in your Maths.hpp file. Or you have a second copy of it someplace. Somewhere that you don't have `static` on the definition of Tau.

Comment: My friend who was using GCC was able to compile it. But I can't even with the exact same settings and without any compiler specifics.

Comment: @GabeNoodle: Then it sounds like the compiler and version you're using would be important information to include in your question.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013.